# Get and Post Object including list of another Object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have 3 Models which belong together:

- Device
- Person
- Inspection

An Inspection could have many devices and one person.

I realized these relations using a separate table:

```java
    @Entity
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @Table(name = "ACTION_INSPECTION")
    public class ActionInspection implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column
        private Long actionInspectionId;
    
        @NotNull
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
        private Person person;
    
        @NotNull
        @JsonProperty("devices")
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "deviceId")
        private Device device;
    
        @NotNull
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "inspectionId")
        private Inspection inspection;
        //endregion

        //constructors and getters & setters
    }
```

Get- and Post-Methods of ActionInspectionController:

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/all")
    public List<ActionInspection> getAllActionInspections() {
        return actionInspectionRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getActionInspectionById(@RequestParam long actionInspectionId ) {

        Optional<ActionInspection> optionalActionInspection = actionInspectionRepository.findById(actionInspectionId);
        ResponseEntity<?> result;

        if (optionalActionInspection.isPresent()) {
            ActionInspection actionInspection = optionalActionInspection.get();
            result = new ResponseEntity<ActionInspection>(actionInspection, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            result = new ResponseEntity<String>(String.format("ActionInspection with Id %d doesn't exist", actionInspectionId), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<?> insertActionInspection(@Valid @RequestBody ActionInspection actionInspection, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        ResponseEntity<?> result = null;
        String errorMessage = "";
        boolean error = false;


        Optional<Person> optionalPerson = personRepository.findById(actionInspection.getPerson().getPersonId());
        Optional<Device> optionalDevice = deviceRepository.findById(actionInspection.getDevice().getDeviceId());

        if (optionalPerson.isPresent())
            actionInspection.setPerson(optionalPerson.get());
        else
            result = new ResponseEntity<String>("Person not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        if (!optionalDevice.isPresent())
            actionInspection.setDevice(optionalDevice.get());
        else
            result = new ResponseEntity<String>("Device not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        try {
            inspectionRepository.save(actionInspection.getInspection());
            actionInspectionRepository.save(actionInspection);

            result = new ResponseEntity<ActionInspection>(actionInspection, HttpStatus.CREATED);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = bindingResult.hasErrors();
            errorMessage = bindingResult.toString();
            result = new ResponseEntity<String>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So, creating a new ActionInspection includes creating a new Inspection as well if needed.

Using the GetMethod to list all ActionInspections I get this:

```json
[
    {
        "actionInspectionId": 1,
        "person": {
            "personId": 1,
            "lastname": "Maier",
            "firstname": "Sepp"
        },
        "inspection": {
            "inspectionId": 3,
            "inspectionDate": "2021-12-31",
            "inspectionState": 2,
            "inspectionInterval": 1.0
        },
        "devices": {
            "deviceId": 3,
            "deviceName": "Kaffeemaschine",
            "deviceState": 2,
            "deviceDescription": "praktisch"
        }
    },
    {
        "actionInspectionId": 2,
        "person": {
            "personId": 1,
            "lastname": "Maier",
            "firstname": "Sepp"
        },
        "inspection": {
            "inspectionId": 3,
            "inspectionDate": "2021-12-31",
            "inspectionState": 2,
            "inspectionInterval": 1.0
        },
        "devices": {
            "deviceId": 2,
            "deviceName": "Farbdrucker",
            "deviceState": 1,
            "deviceDescription": "sehr leise"
        }
    }
]
```

But I need to get and post Json which includes a list of all devices which belongs to the same inspection(Id):

```json
[
  {
    "person": {
      "personId": 1,
      "lastname": "Maier",
      "firstname": "Sepp"
    },
    "inspection": {
      "inspectionId": 3,
      "inspectionDate": "2021-12-31",
      "inspectionState": 2,
      "inspectionInterval": 1
    },
    "devices": [
      {
        "deviceId": 3,
        "deviceName": "Kaffeemaschine",
        "deviceState": 2,
        "deviceDescription": "praktisch"
      },
      {
        "deviceId": 2,
        "deviceName": "Farbdrucker",
        "deviceState": 1,
        "deviceDescription": "sehr leise"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way I can realize this?

Many thanks in advance for every input I'll get - also for criticism (no matter if good or bad).

Comment: I am not sure if there is a good way with `@Query`/HQL but you could use `@ManyToMany` for a device list (another mapping table device-actionInspections)  or you could sort them by hand and use another 'view object' for it

Comment: you question said 'An Inspection could have many devices' but the `ActionInspection` class shows only 1 `Device`. per `ActionInspection`

Comment: So, thank you both. Now I removed ActionInspection and made a ManyToMany-Relationship between Inspection and Device. No it's easy to get and post Inspections including a list of other Devices - it's much more easier to handle it this way.